# Can you explain the difference in behavior of sending a parameter as function with and without parentheses?

Tags: python

Here what seems weird to me.

I have defined a function:

```
def whatever():
  <<doing whatever>>
```

I used it in the main window loop like that:

```
whatever()
```

but I also call it from somewhere (when an event takes place in some other function) this way:

```
<<something else happens>>
window.after(1000, whatever)
```

The above works fine. But, when I mistakenly did this:

window.after(1000, whatever())

...it still seemed to work, but I got no waiting!

Now, after more thinking, it probably just executed "whatever()" in the main window loop and not the one above (inside "window.after"), but still I don't understand:

- Why it didn't produce any error (or even a warning by IDE).
- Why it didn't wait anyway before going back to the main loop (since it didn't trigger any failure state).

Thanks.

Comment: Why would it error? Maybe whatever is a higher-order function that returns a function to be passed to after.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.after(1000, whatever)
```

Here, you're passing a *reference* to the function "whatever" to `window.after`. So that when 1000 ms have passed, the `whatever` function gets called.

```
window.after(1000, whatever())
```

Here, you're calling the `whatever()` function immediately, and are passing the *return value of `whatever()`* to `window.after`.

For a concrete example:

```
def whatever():
    print("foo")
    return 123

window.after(1000, whatever)
// prints nothing at this time, then after 1000 ms calls whatever() and prints "foo"

window.after(1000, whatever())
// prints "foo" immediately and essentially calls window.after(1000, 123)
```

This particular example would cause an error, since you can't do `window.after(1000, 123)` since `123` is not a function.

If `whatever` has no return value (or returns `None`) this would not cause an error, since the callback argument [may be `None`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html).

Answer (score 0):

The function just gets called when the statement is run and then passes its return value instead.